# Customized bootstrap doesn't have breakpoint for XS screen size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I only wanted the CSS for the Grid layout and Responsive utilities, so I customized boostrap for my application here - http://getbootstrap.com/customize/?id=568dcb34f5eabdd2e526e20c7041d8bc

Part of the default settings on that page define where common breakpoints are -

[image]

When I downloaded my customized file, I noticed media queries for the breakpoints 768px, 992px, and 1200px. But I didn't see anything about 480px.

Is there a reason for that? I know the CSS file is structured to applyl to the smallest resolution first and then increase in resolution progressively, but wouldn't their still be a break point for less than and greater than 480px?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact reason for missing the breakpoint of 480px but, In the new version of Bootstrap, Bootstrap 4, there is a new breakpoint (XS). That breapoint is not 480px, but < 544px.

Check it out here http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/